# not able to pop to viewcontroller more than once using uiswipegesturerecognizer default feature

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Hello I am working on swift 4.0 and Xcode 10.2. 
I have added the following code to pop previous controller. If suppose I push three controller one by one then `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` can able to pop only once after that its not working.I am giving the following code details.I am stuck on this point and not getting any related answer.

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.isEnabled = true
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.delegate = self
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Please give me solution.

Comment: `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is the default functionality of `navigationController`. You don't need to add any code for it.

Comment: Thanks for reply,                                                                                           
Actually in some condition I have to disable it and in some condition I have to enable so that I need the put the above code. But still I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've created the a similar hierarchy as yours with 3 controllers - `VC1, VC2 and VC3`

[image]

You can handle the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` in controllers as follows:

1. Set the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self`
2. Implement `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)` method to return true/false to enable/diable the `gesture`.

**Example:**

In `VC2`: `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is `disabled`

In `VC3`: `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is `enabled`

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class VC2: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}

class VC3: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

There is no need to manually set `isEnabled` property of `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` everytime in different `controllers`, i.e. remove the below code,

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
```

Comment: Not yet. I supposed I am facing the issue because due to hide the navigation bar from storyboard and programmatically across complete project.                                  Thanks